# Creating a row from multiple dataframes even if the categorical values are missing in R

Tags: r

So I'm trying to build a function that reads data frames and binds them to a summarized row for each. These data frames go through the mutate listed below (included in this example only for testing). The purpose in the end is to create one row from dataframe 1 and then bind the created rows from dataframe 2, dataframe 3, etc into a table...Some of these dataframes are missing some of the values in the "new_cat" so they do not bind properly (the select breaks since it cannot find the value). This workaround was successful in keeping the row but of course I'm losing the original value if present. My question is if there is a way to have it conditional based on if the value was present for it to be kept and for those that are not present to be kept as "0" that way i have a full table with no missing values. I tried `mutate(ifelse("A" == TRUE,"A",0)` but I'm probably missing any sensible logic there. Version 2, shows a somewhat working version of the code but of course it only includes the values that are present in the data frame, I want to keep those and the ones that are missing. Any help is appreciated.

```
test_df <- data.frame(old_cat = c("A_Old","B_Old","C_Old","D_Old","E_Old","J_Old","Y_Old"))

outcomes <- test_df %>%
    mutate(new_cat = case_when(old_cat == "A_Old" ~ "A",
                               old_cat == "B_Old" ~ "A",
                               old_cat == "C_Old" ~ "B",
                               old_cat == "D_Old" ~ "B",
                               old_cat == "E_Old" ~ "C",
                               TRUE ~ "Other")) %>%   
group_by(new_cat) %>%   
summarize(total=n()) %>%   
spread(new_cat,total)
{if (all(names(outcomes) 
           %in%c("A","B","C","Other")))   outcomes %>% 
      mutate(`A` = 0,
             `B` = 0,
             `C` = 0,
             `Other` = 0)   } %>%
#purpose is to order them   
select(`B`,`C`,`A`,`Other`)
```

```
Version 2
test_df2 <- data.frame(old_cat = c("D_Old","J_Old","Y_Old"))

outcomes <- test_df2 %>%
    mutate(new_cat = case_when(old_cat == "A_Old" ~ "A",
                               old_cat == "B_Old" ~ "A",
                               old_cat == "C_Old" ~ "B",
                               old_cat == "D_Old" ~ "B",
                               old_cat == "E_Old" ~ "C",
                               TRUE ~ "Other")) %>%   
group_by(new_cat) %>%   
summarize(total=n()) %>%   
spread(new_cat,total)
{if (all(names(outcomes) 
           %in%c("A","Other")))   outcomes %>% 
      mutate(`A` = 0,
             #`B` = 0,
             #`C` = 0,
             `Other` = 0)   } #%>%
#purpose is to order them   
#select(`B`,`C`,`A`,`Other`)
```

Expected outcome for the row:

if the dataframe has no "A" or "B" but has 3 "C" and 7 "Other".

```
   | B | C | A | Other

    | 0 | 3 | 0 | 7
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Perhaps you need `complete`, but without the expected output, it is not clear

Comment: @akrun i added an expected outcome. Hope that helps, please let me know if I didn't explain myself properly. The point is to keep the missing values. However, I cannot know for sure which value will be missing since it's intended as a function.

Comment: The  7 for Other is not clear to me

Comment: So let's say one of the data frames has a total of 3 "C" and has some random letters that are not A,B or C. The 7 are put together as "Other" hence where the 7 comes from.

Comment: In your code, you are changing the 'C_Old' and 'D_Old' to "B" and "E_Old" to "C".  Does this represents your actual data?  The reason I ask is that if we create a code based on this info, it could fail on your actual data

Comment: I apologize, I tried to make this data anonymous and in the process it confuses me. The expected out come if for the newly mutated categories. The "old" ones are not to be used again. There shouldn't be an other on the original data, I'll make some edits for it to make more sense.

Comment: Here the data is very specific to 'A_old', 'B_old', etc. if we do the `==` or `%in%`, it would need to match exact strings

Comment: I updated the code so it runs for anyone (the piping worked in my code because i had the outcomes loaded already). This code should run now without issues. My trouble is with `{if (all(names(outcomes) 
           %in%c("A","B","C","Other")))   outcomes %>% 
      mutate(`A` = 0,
             `B` = 0,
             `C` = 0,
             `Other` = 0)   } ` This is particularly where I want to take into consideration any potential missing values. I added Version 2 of the code to show a somewhat working code with a different dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workflow that has a couple of meaningful changes from your current flow:

- starts with a list of frames, with the assumption that we're going to rename them accordingly and then combine them;
- uses a "merge"/"join" operation to rename them;
- reshapes using the newer `tidyr::pivot_wider`, and while `spread` is not even soft-deprecated yet, I generally think it's best to shift to the newer `pivot_*` functions with their power and flexibility.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_wider
library(purrr) # map_dfr

test_df <- data.frame(old_cat = c("A_Old","B_Old","C_Old","D_Old","E_Old","J_Old","Y_Old"))
test_df2 <- data.frame(old_cat = c("D_Old","J_Old","Y_Old"))
conversions <- tibble(
  old_cat = c("A_Old","B_Old","C_Old","D_Old","E_Old","J_Old","Y_Old"),
  new_cat = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "Other", "Other")
)

list(test_df, test_df2) %>%
  map_dfr(., ~ left_join(., conversions, by = "old_cat") %>%
               group_by(new_cat) %>%
               tally(),
          .id = "id") %>%
  pivot_wider(id, names_from = new_cat, values_from = n,
              values_fill = list(n = 0L)) %>%
  select(B, C, A, Other)
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#       B     C     A Other
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     2     1     2     2
# 2     1     0     0     2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This ended up helping me!!

Comment: let's say that one of these dataframes that I'm putting in the list, has another column listed as A1,A2,A3 and I wanted to get the totals for these added to the final table (so it's a conditional if when grouped by that column in particular to get the total number of new_cat for that particular column). Is this possible in this code? It's literally just one dataframe that has this different column.

Comment: I tried taking that particular data frame and just doing a group_by but that didn't work. I'm guessing this may be something that has to be done before the code you provided?

Comment: I'm not following what you're saying about the new frame.

Comment: Sorry, ignore what I said as confused myself lol. One of the issues I am having with this is in the case of one of the listed dataframe being empty (having no observations from any previous filters). Is there a way to keep this dataframe as a row as just all zeros? Thank you.

Comment: I'm usually quite careful to distinguish between "empty" (no data) and zeroes, since `0` can be a valid non-empty value. For those situations, I prefer `NA`. Ultimately, it is up to you to know what is valid data. Before `map_dfr`, try adding `%>% map(., ~ if (NROW(.) > 0) . else { .[1,] <- NA; .; })`.

Comment: Thank you again for the help! This works as intended!! Never really been familiar with the map functions but liking them so far!

Comment: They are sometimes considered a safer and at times more convenient alternative to base R's `sapply`, `lapply`, `vapply`, `mapply`, and `Map` functions. I tend to use `lapply` because it is "safe" in many ways, but when already loading `purrr` and there is a need to combine later, then the `map_*` functions add a lot of convenience. Glad this helps.